# Install oracle client in docker container

Tags: oracle, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, oracleclient

I am using alpine linux as a base image, and I need to install an oracle client native library. I believe you can download from here:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

1. it looks like I have to login to download, does anyone know how to download a zip file of the client lib without login?
2. does anyone know how to install the client library properly in a bash script or dockerfile?

Comment: For the record, recent Instant Clients can be downloaded without login or clickthrough.

Answer (score 12):

I have figure out some different way to install Oracle instant client in `ubuntu` Docker, it might help others

Follow these simple steps:

1. Download oracle instant client (`.rpm` file) from [oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) official download center
2. Convert into `.deb` (you can use `apt-get install alien` )  and move somewhere in your working directory.
3. Now Update your `Dockerfile` and make build

   ```
   RUN apt-get update
   WORKDIR /opt
   ADD ./ORACLE-INSTANT-CLIENT.deb  /opt
   #if libaio also required
   RUN apt-get install libaio1 
   RUN dpkg -i oracle-instantclient.deb
   ```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a working solution for the official PHP-FPM images based on Debian 10 (Buster). The following `Dockerfile` installs the Oracle Instant Client 18.5 (*basiclite* and *devel*) using the RPM packges and `alien`.

As Christopher Jones wrote the files can currently be downloaded without an Oracle account.

```
FROM php:7.2.32-fpm

# see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends alien libaio1 wget && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/185000/oracle-instantclient18.5-basiclite-18.5.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/185000/oracle-instantclient18.5-devel-18.5.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm && \
    alien -i oracle-instantclient18.5-basiclite-18.5.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm && \
    alien -i oracle-instantclient18.5-devel-18.5.0.0.0-3.x86_64.rpm
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Comment: I thought alien converted the RPM package's ldconfig postinstall script.  If it does convert it, then you don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH  (Adn you can get 19.8 now, which connects to the same DB versions as 18)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to download oracle at runtime then you can run the below commands

```
FROM ruby:3.0


ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev zlib1g-dev build-essential shared-mime-info libaio1 libaio-dev unzip wget --no-install-recommends && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/214000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/214000/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/214000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    mkdir -p /opt/oracle && \
    cp instantclient-* /opt/oracle/ && \
    cd /opt/oracle/ && \
    unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    apt -y clean && \
    apt -y remove wget unzip && \
    apt -y autoremove && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt
```

You can download the specific version of instantclient by specifying the version above

These two packages are require for ruby-oci if you are using ruby on rails application

**libaio1**

**libaio-dev**

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use Alpine Linux, since you will need to hack it and it could become unstable.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53291026/4799035 for more comments.

Also see https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/19/Dockerfile which doesn't need any login.

In summary, on Oracle Linux 7:

```
yum -y install oracle-release-el7
yum -y install oracle-instantclient19.3-basic && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

Update: Oracle has Docker images at https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/pkgs/container/oraclelinux7-instantclient and https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/pkgs/container/oraclelinux8-instantclient which can be pulled like:

```
docker pull ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux7-instantclient:21
```

and

```
docker pull ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-instantclient:21
```

Comment: docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/instantclient:latest not working. Please update it.

Comment: Use the Dockerfiles and customize to your needs.

Comment: There are now pre-built images with Instant Client at https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/pkgs/container/oraclelinux8-instantclient and similar for Oracle Linux 7.  You can pull with `docker pull ghcr.io/oracle/oraclelinux8-instantclient:21`

Comment: Is ghcr.io/oracle available, I get a 404?

Comment: Checking the links like https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/pkgs/container/oraclelinux8-instantclient shows the commands are correct.

Comment: So, how do i use this image in my dockerfile instead of pulling it? I guess i am asking a very basic question about using dockerfile but any help on this is appreciated. I am trying to use instantclient on a python app that is going to run in a container. I used to have the syntax of dockerfile starting as `FROM python:3`, which i think is now implicit on Oraclelinux:8, but should i use from `oraclelinux8-instantclient:21` instead?

Comment: @Ak777 see [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python). Note that with [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a), which is the most recent Python driver for Oracle DB, most people don't need to install Instant Client at all.

Comment: This really solved by switching to "oracledb" library instead of "cx_oracle" and i completely ignored the instant client installation in my docker and it works like charm. This is purely my case where i am going with light weight oracledb, where i need to READ data and using sqlalchemy > 2.0.0 to support oracledb.

Answer (score 1):

As Oracle official state:
Instant Client is available for Docker
Dockerfiles are available on GitHub. Pre-built images are available from the GitHub Container Registry.
Here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html