# Unable to connect oracle 19c thick mode using airflow

Tags: docker, airflow, oracleclient

I trying to connect oracle 19c using airflow thick mode.

1.I downlaoded the airflow docker-compose.yml from https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.7.2/docker-compose.yaml

2.I downloaded the oracle client docker file from  https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleInstantClient/oraclelinux8/19/Dockerfile

3.I built custom dependenies with below comamnds in docker file

FROM apache/airflow:2.7.2
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-airflow-providers-oracle===3.7.4
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-airflow-providers-postgres===5.6.1

i built oracle client image using below command based on step 2 docker file
docker build .  --tag oracleclient19

i added the custom built dependencies with airflow 2.7.2 image in docker-compose.yaml  as wells oracle client image.

run the airflow using below commands
docker compose up airflow-init
docker compose up

it is up and unable to connect db.
i am getting below error
**(DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/usr/lib/oracle/19.20/client64/libclntsh.so
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"**

i should be able to connect db to extract data

my custom oracle client docker container not running
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmPnN.png)

i tried using astro as well.unable to start
[Unable to connect oracle 19c using thick mode in airflow using astro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77395634/unable-to-connect-oracle-19c-using-thick-mode-in-airflow-using-astro)

Comment: Can you check this answer? ->https://stackoverflow.com/a/58217923/2890093

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to download the Oracle instantclient, unzip it and put it in your container with a basic COPY command. The environment variable then tells it where to find the files. Or you could copy the files to the directory oracle was expecting.

```
COPY instantclient_21_13 /instantclient_21_13
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/instantclient_21_13"
```