# Alpine dependency hell with Oracle Instant client

Tags: python, docker, cx-oracle, alpine-linux, oracleclient

**I'm trying to make oracle connections from my Alpine Linux container using cx_Oracle(which needs oracle instant client). cx_oracle keeps complaining about different missing libraries which are required for Oracle instant-client**

Error:

> con = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass@127.0.0.1/orcl') Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>
> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit
> Oracle Client library: "Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No
> such file or directory (needed by /usr/lib/libclntsh.so)".

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine-base
COPY /app /base/app
COPY requirements.txt /base
COPY instantclient_12_2.zip /base
COPY instantclient_sqlplus_12_2.zip /base
COPY run_app.py /base
COPY oratest.py /base/oratest.py
WORKDIR /base
RUN apk add libaio libnsl openssl-dev musl-dev libffi-dev && \
    apk add openssl-dev && \
    pip install cryptography==2.2.2 && \  
    apk add libressl-dev && \
    pip install cx_Oracle
    unzip /base/instantclient_12_2.zip && \
    unzip /base/instantclient_sqlplus_12_2.zip && \
    mv /base/instantclient_12_2/ /usr/lib/ && \
    rm -rf /base/instantclient_12_2.zip && \
    ln /usr/lib/instantclient_12_2/libclntsh.so.12.1 /usr/lib/libclntsh.so && \
    ln /usr/lib/instantclient_12_2/libocci.so.12.1 /usr/lib/libocci.so && \
    ln /usr/lib/instantclient_12_2/libociei.so /usr/lib/libociei.so && \
    ln /usr/lib/instantclient_12_2/libnnz12.so /usr/lib/libnnz12.so
ENV ORACLE_BASE /usr/lib/instantclient_12_2
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/instantclient_12_2
ENV TNS_ADMIN /usr/lib/instantclient_12_2
ENV ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/instantclient_12_2
RUN pip install -r /base/requirements.txt 
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "python", "/base/run_app.py" ]
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?
I'm pretty much done with fighting the dependencies for oracle instant client - is there a better way of making Oracle connections from alpine

I would like to see if anyone had success running cx_Oracle in alpine linux

Answer (score 1):

You can probably install libnsl to get past this one (https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/libnsl), but—I suggest just avoiding Alpine.

1. You don't get binary wheels, so you have to compile packages yourself, which makes things harder and your images bigger.
2. The C library is different enough that some things occasionally break.

All for the benefit of an only slightly smaller image (assuming need for compiler didn't make it bigger in the end).

Long version: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/

Comment: I'm already installing libnsl- But everytime I resolve one dependency, the oracle client will find another missing library. I think I'm done hacking alpine will start using ubuntu.

Comment: It is more about security than being small. I've got quite far with another library (swift) but somehow even after installing and symlinking to v2 its not finding the lib ... for now .. i'll link the solution once i get it working ...

Answer (score 0):

To repeat my [earlier views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53291026/4799035):

I'd recommend using an operating system supported by Oracle, thus avoiding the headache of hacking Alpine and the uncertainty that it won't fall over at a critical time. And thus giving you some confidence your business won't be negatively impacted. Try https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/19/Dockerfile